# What can happen when loading a YAML file from an untrusted source with SnakeYAML?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

The [SnakeYAML](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/) documentation [says](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Tutorial):

> Warning: It is not safe to call `Yaml.load()` with any data received from an untrusted source!

Is it security issues? What can a malicious YAML file do?

Comment: It could run malicious code.

Comment: @Brian So YAML files can contain Java code, that will be executed while parsing?

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering about this, too, and found the following in the documentation:

> Note if you want to limit objects to standard Java objects like List
>   or Long you need [to use SafeConstructor](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/examples/SafeConstructorExampleTest.java).
>
> ```
> Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new SafeConstructor());
> ```

The link quoted above goes to a test case in which a YAML document contains a reference to a Java object.  Without `SafeConstructor`, `yaml.load` would call the object's no-argument constructor and this might be a bad thing for some classes in your classpath.  With `SafeConstructor`, only the [`SafeConstructor` nested classes](http://snakeyamlrepo.appspot.com/releases/1.10/site/apidocs/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/SafeConstructor.html) ([Java code](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/SafeConstructor.java)) would ever be called.

Answer (score 0):

SnakeYAML allows to use any class loader. When the instance of a class is created, it calls the constructor. It will run any code there. If you load classes yourself - no worries.

Comment: What do you mean by "load classes yourself"?